# How to delete the content of a list not only the list? If x is in y, delete y as well when x is deleted

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collections,

- Classrooms
- Students

Here are their schema

```
**CLASSROOM SCHEMA**

const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const classroomSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  classroomname:  {
    type: String
  },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  author: {
    id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "User",

    },
   },
  students: {
    id : {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Student"
    }
  }

});

const Classroom = mongoose.model('Classroom', classroomSchema);

module.exports = Classroom;
```

and..

```
**STUDENT SCHEMA**

const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: {
        type: String
    },
    author: {
    id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "User",

    },
   }, 
    classroom: {
                name: {
                        type: String
                        },
                id: {
                        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
                        ref: "classroom",
                    }
                },

});

const Student = mongoose.model('Student', studentSchema);

module.exports = Student;
```

This is how **Students** look like
[image]

- where author.id is the user.id, who created the student after logged
  in.

I do have the following code for successfully deleting a student

```
router.get('/delete/:id',passportConfig.isAuthenticated,(req, res) => {


    Student.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, docs) => {
            if (!err) {
                res.redirect('/');
            }
            else {console.log('Error in classroom deletion:' +err);}

        });

    });
```

..and a very similar code for deleting a Classroom.
My question is,
How, when I delete a Classroom to delete all the students belonging to that classroom as well?

Here would be my logic

```
find classroom id
find student.classroom.id
if student.classroom.id == classroom.id
Classroom, Student findbyid and remove
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below Code will be help :

> req.params.id should be classroom id.

```
router.get('/delete/:id',passportConfig.isAuthenticated,(req, res) => {
  // To Delete Classroom by id 
  Classroom.remove({_id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, (errClass, classroomRes) => { 
    if (!errClass) {
    console.log('Classroom Removed :',classroomRes);
    // delete stud which has classroom Id.
      Student.remove({'classroom.id' : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId(req.params.id)}, (errStud, studentRes) => { 
        if(!errStud){
            console.log('studentRes Removed :',studentRes);
        }else{
            console.log('Error in Student deletion:',errStud);
        }
        return res.redirect('/');
      });

    }else{
       console.log('Error in Classroom deletion:',errClass);
       return res.redirect('/');
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: works like a charm, the only modification needed was:  "mongoose.Types.ObjectId" instead of mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId. Thank you!